# Ohmic Heating in Wires

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

please could someone tell me why Ohmic losses are always referred to as $I^2 R$ losses? Here is my problem. If the power coming from a power station is fixed then you can either deliver this power as high voltage, low current or high current, low voltage. But isn't $I^2R$ equal to $V^2 / R$, therefore if R is constant doesn't the power depend on the square of the voltage so surely it doesn't matter whether it is high voltage or high current. The only way I can reconcile this is that a high current must cause a greater heating effect than a high voltage. I can't figure why though. If this is the case then is there a reason why a high current causes more heating than a high voltage?

Comment: You have to include the load resistance in your calculations, and then compare the power dissipated in the wires (with a constant resistance) and the power dissipated in the load.

Comment: If you want to design for $P_{loss}=I^2R=V^2/R=const.$, then you have to choose a low resistance for high current and you can chose a large resistance for high voltage. For the same length of wire the resistance should be as high as possible, since the amount of (expensive!) metal (usually copper) increases significantly if you need thick, low resistance wires operating at a low voltage. In other words, insulators (like air) are significantly cheaper than good conductors like copper.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. If you have a fixed resistance then why does ohmic heating depend more strongly on current than voltage?

Comment: It does not. The dependence is $P = UI$.

Answer (score 2):

> But isn't $I^2R$ equal to $V^2/R$, therefore if $R$ is constant doesn't the power depend on the square of the voltage so surely it doesn't matter whether it is high voltage or high current.

Consider the wires connecting the power plant to the appliance; let the effective amplitude of oscillating current flowing through all wires be $I$ and let $V$ be drop of electric potential across *one* wire conducting current $I$. The situation can be drawn like this:

```
              V
  <------------------------>
  o‒‒∧‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒o
     |  
     |U
  o‒‒∨‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒o


  o‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒‒o

power                     appliance
plant
```

The Joule loss of energy per unit time in the wires is $P_{loss}=VI$ and since  Ohm's law says $V=I/R$, we have expressions $P_{loss}=V^2/R= I^2R$.

When people say higher voltage means lower losses of energy, by "voltage" they do not mean $V$; that would make, as you realized, no sense since the energy losses are proportional both to $I^2$ and to $V^2$.

By "higher voltage", they mean higher voltage $U$ between *two separate wires* at the same distance from the power plant. Higher $U$ than generated can be achieved in the power plant using appropriate voltage transformer.

Why is higher $U$ beneficial?

The power utilizable at the end of the power line is $P_{useful}=UI$. The power that is being lost is $RI^2$.

So by making $U$ higher, the same useful power can be transferred with much lower current $I$ and thus much lower energy losses $RI^2$ in the power line. It is easy too see that if we double the voltage $U$, the power loss decreases by factor of four.

Answer (score 1):

If the only load is the wire, such as a hot wire cutter, then supply voltage and wire resistance are all that matter, and both formulas are equivalent.

But most of the time, wire size is chosen so that most of the voltage appears on the load. As an example, a toaster uses a power cord with wires which drop much less voltage than the heaters - if this were not done, the power cord wires would get as hot as the toaster.

With most of the voltage being dropped by the load and not the wires, it is the load resistance which sets the current in both the load and the wires. As far as the wires are concerned, the supply voltage becomes pretty much irrelevant, so the power dissipated is viewed in terms of the current only.

For example, if the load resistance is 100 times the wire resistance, a 5% difference in the load resistance will cause a 10% variation in the wire power, but at 5% difference in the wire resistance will cause a .01% variation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I get what you are saying. Are you saying that the load resistance is much higher than the resistance of the conducting wires, therefore pretty much all the voltage is lost across the load meaning that only the current through the wires plays a role in power dissipation of the wires? So even if there was a large drop in the load, the load will still get all the voltage but the current will increase, causing heating in the wires?

Comment: Close enough, but not exactly. When the load resistance is much larger than the wire resistance (which is what you want) it's the load which determines how much current flows, so the ohmic heating in the wires does not depend (much) on the relationship of voltage to wire resistance. You can take that into account, but it's just easier to calculate the current drawn by the load and apply that current to the wires.

Comment: So to answer the question "why does ohmic heating depend on current rather than voltage" can I say that voltage doesn't come into play because the load will always take most (if not all) the voltage since the load resistance will always be significantly higher than the wires. Therefore, it is pretty much only the current that dictates the power loss to the wires (which is the product of the current in the wire and the wire's resistance). Would that be a satisfactory answer?

Comment: I came across an example of where I can't seem to explain the heating effect through what was discussed in this post. Consider a semi-conductor where the resistance decreases as temperature increases. Apparently it is wrong to attribute the increase in temperature of the semi-conductor to the voltage - it is the current that does this. If you look at the I-V characteristic then you can see a curve showing resistance decreases but why can't you explain this through the voltage since the voltage plotted is the voltage across the semi-conductor so as this increases surely the temperature does?

Comment: If you fix the voltage at some level, then the power dissipated in the semiconductor varies only with the current. Other than that, I'm afraid you've misunderstood what you read. Power depends both on voltage and current.

Comment: I understand it as you say. I would say that when voltage is not fixed then both current and power add to heating. However, I was doing an exam question where it showed an I-V graph for a semi-conductor and it asked you to explain why the resistance decreases and the answer must explain how the temperature in the semiconductor changes. The markscheme clearly stated that it would only allow P = I^2R to justify the temperature rise and not any references to temperature rise being linked to voltage which makes no sense to me as voltage is not fixed here!

Comment: Without seeing the curve or the question, I can't help you.

Comment: Here is the link to question paper (http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/175458-question-paper-unit-g482-01-electrons-waves-and-photons.pdf). It is question 1 c. Here is the markscheme (http://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/176278-mark-scheme-unit-g482-electrons-waves-and-photons-june.pdf). I checked the examiners notes as well as they tell you how previous people generally answered this question and it says "On question 1c students tended to incorrectly attribute the rise in temperature in the semi-conducting slice to an increase in voltage". Any help understanding this would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a little tricky. Unspoken is the assumption that the material is not kept at a constant temperature. At 4 volts, current is 8 mA. At 8 volts, current is 26 mA. If resistance were constant, at 8 volts current would be 16 mA. So as the power in the slab increased, and it got warmer, its resistance (and resistivity) decreased. I've no idea why I^2 R is acceptable while V^2/R is not.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Would you say that the exam board are incorrect in saying that V^2/R is not acceptable?

Comment: Given that they express the same thing, yes. Unless, for instance, they take the deeper physical interpretation the ohmic heating is caused by moving electrons bumping around in the material, and the measure of electron (collective) motion is current. I don't know what was presented in class.

Comment: Thanks again. Even if they take this deeper physical meaning surely heating is not just caused by the current? it must also be linked to the energy each electron has which is linked to voltage? Or are you saying that ohmic heating in particular is only caused by current and not by voltage?

Comment: No, only that I don't know what was presented in class.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding $0.02 for clarity:

The formulas $I^2R$ and $V^2/R$ describe the power dissipated *in a resistor*.

If you're considering the power lost in power transmission lines, the "resistor" is the power line, not the appliance in the home where the power is wanted.

The $V$ in the $V^2/R$ formula is the voltage beetween the two ends of the resistor so, in the power transmission problem, $V$ is not the voltage delivered to the home:  It's the voltage *difference* between one end of the transmission line and the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember ohms law
$$V=IR$$
If you have a high voltage across a resistor, you automatically get a high current because they're related. If you have high current, you're going to need a high voltage to drive it. It's referred to as $I^2R$ by convention and for convenience; $V^2/R$ or even $VI$ are equally valid.